# Quickbooks .IIF file invoice

Tags: c#, quickbooks, invoice, iif

I'm creating an application that can export an .IIF file, that can be imported on quickbooks as invoice. Anyone got a sample format of .IIF invoice? that can also automate "item, "description", "quantity", "rate", "amount", "tax".

Now, i was able to import only the vendor name. and the items but its still on the list that needs to manually be selected on quickbooks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm creating an application that can export an .IIF file,

.IIF files have been deprecated, and officially unsupported, for 10+ years now.

They are known to cause corruption to QuickBooks data files.

Do not use them.

Use the [QuickBooks SDK](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb) instead. It provides a XML/COM interface directly to QuickBooks that is very well documented and reliable.

Comment: What if I don't want to create an entire app with the sdk and just want to export a simple invoice and have our users import that single invoice into quick books?

Comment: What I said above still stands. The SDK is the best way. IIF files can cause corruption and are deprecated. The SDK is very easy to use to create tiny little export tools just as you've described. No need to create anything big and bulky.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr.  We have a .NET web app, this would require us to have our customers install the QB Web Connector, and then we can write an export tool that syncs data to the QB Web Connector, which then syncs the data into QuickBooks Desktop right?

Comment: @TWilly The QuickBooks Web Connector comes bundled with QuickBooks -- it's already installed. You'd write a SOAP web service which talks to the Web Connector to sync data into QuickBooks desktop.

Comment: IIF files don't seem to be deprecated, as Intuit just updated the import process for 2019: 

https://quickbooks.intuit.com/community/Help-Articles/Improved-IIF-Import-in-QuickBooks-2019/m-p/203267

Comment: They were, and they sort of un-deprecated them and improved them (made them run through validation). They still are not a recommended route (the SDK is much, much nicer from a end-user-friendliness perspective).